# Celsius to Fahrenheit trs-80 basic

Tags: basic

Does anyone remember the old old old BASIC code for converting Fahrenheit to Celsius?  I'd really appreciate it if someone would post the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following [PDF](http://www.1000bit.it/support/manuali/trs/Introduction%20to%20TRS-80%20Level%20II%20BASIC%20(1980)(Michael%20Zabinski)(pdf).pdf), on page 40 (pdf page 57):

The code would be something like, for Level II BASIC:

```
10 INPUT "FAHRENHEIT: "; F
20 C = 5 * (F - 32) / 9
30 PRINT F; " FAHRENHEIT IS "; C; " CELSIUS"
40 GOTO 10
```

If you're using the Model I with Level I BASIC, or some other severely limited TRS-80, you may need something even simpler.

Comment: How do you know it's not the Model I, Level I? Or the CoCo? Or, $DEITY forbid, the Model 100? :-)

Comment: Very cool! but I am looking for even an older version. :)

Comment: @Red, then you need to specify _which_ version. Unless you're trolling of course, which I'm very much starting to suspect :-)

Comment: Sorry not trolling. really I am sorry I was just hoping an trs-80 hobbyist would have an answer :)

Comment: @Red, not a hobbyist, but I did cut my teeth on these beasts. This answer is the one you want, bringing the code over, slightly modified, so you don't have to search through an ancient PDF.

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
INPUT "Enter Fahrenheit "; FAHR20 : PRINT "Celsius is ", (FAHR-32) * 5 / 9
```

Comment: No. The old original BASIC code. Every line started with an integer and goto was considered good coding style.

Comment: @Red, `GOTO` wasn't consider good style by the way, Dijkstra had made that clear in the 60s, _long_ before the Trash80 came into existence. It's just that there was no alternative :-)